# Replacing characters in the middle of a line in a text file with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, file, replace

I have the code below that I use to replace a string within a text file and it works. However; I have run into the problem where the string I want to replace is not always exactly the same, but the first few characters are. I want to find the first few characters, count 3 characters ahead, and replace that with what I want.

For example, the line I am replacing may be `123xxx`, or `123aaa`, etc. but the value I am replacing it with is always going to be known. How would I go about replacing the `123xxx` when I won't always know what the `xxx` is?

```
((Get-Content -path $ConfPath -Raw) -replace $OldVersion,$NewVersion) | Set-Content -Path $ConfPath
```

Comment: The -replace parameter accepts regex, you could write a pattern for that. If you want i provide you an answer with the solution.

Comment: Steve welcome to SO. You should provide a better example. Perhaps some sample full lines, what you want to remove, and expected result. That would help everyone to give you better assistance.

Comment: `$string -replace '123...',$newvalue`

Comment: A little confusing to explain, but i will attempt to. The string in the file I want to replace would be "jre1.8.0_251", but I will not always know what the 3 digits at the end are. they could be any 3 number. I want to replace it with "jre1.8.0_261", which I know will always be the same. My question is how to say I want to replace "jre1.8.0_251" without knowing the last 3 digits. I am looking at regex but not really understanding it right now. I guess I have not found a good enough article that explains it to me.

Comment: So basically I want to replace "jre1.8.0_" plus 3 characters with "jre1.8.0_261". This string is in a file that contains a lot of text, but that string is only in one place in the file and at the end of the line it is in, so right after the 3 characters would be a new line character I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `-replace` uses regex, you need to escape the characters that have special meaning like in your case the dot (*any character* in regex).

```
$OldVersion = 'jre1\.8\.0_\d{3}'  # backslash escape the dots.  \d{3} means 3 digits
$NewVersion = 'jre1.8.0_261'      # this is just a string to replace with; not regex
((Get-Content -path $ConfPath -Raw) -replace $OldVersion,$NewVersion) | Set-Content -Path $ConfPath
```

Answer (score 0):

I researched it and figured it out using regex. The code below does exactly what I wanted to do:

```
((Get-Content -path $ConfPath -Raw) -replace 'jre1.8.0_...',$NewVersion) | Set-Content -Path $ConfPath
```